# Client.exe dump file through WinDbg:

Tags: windbg

Been trying to solve why this app is crashing on only one Windows 7 computer and running fine when installed on 5 others.  The program is part of a camera security system which client.exe contacts an internal server and then brings up cameras into an application viewer.  The program connects and starts to load a couple of the streaming video windows then crashes.  This is the most recent dump file.  Antivirus has been removed.  DotNet verifyer tools has been run on the machine.  Memory upgraded from 4GB to 8GB.  All windows updates are current.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17336 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\Client.exe.4756.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\Symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Sat Jan 16 08:35:29.000 2016 (UTC - 5:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:01:35.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
........................................
Loading unloaded module list
..
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(1294.584): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa:
00000000`77badf6a c3              ret
0:051> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for WindowsBase.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for PresentationFramework.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Management.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for icudt48.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for atiumd64.dll - 

FAULTING_IP: 
ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+ee8a4b
00000000`631fbceb c5fa6f0f        vmovdqu xmm1,xmmword ptr [rdi]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000631fbceb (ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+0x0000000000ee8a4b)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 00000000379af220
Attempt to read from address 00000000379af220

CONTEXT:  0000000000000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
rax=00000000c0000001 rbx=000000003a37e290 rcx=0000000007200000
rdx=0000000000000001 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000002
rip=0000000077badf6a rsp=000000003a37e158 rbp=0000000000000002
 r8=000000003a37d878  r9=000000003a37d9e0 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000246 r12=0000000000000000 r13=000000003a37e200
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa:
00000000`77badf6a c3              ret

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

PROCESS_NAME:  Client.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000379af220

READ_ADDRESS:  00000000379af220 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+ee8a4b
00000000`631fbceb c5fa6f0f        vmovdqu xmm1,xmmword ptr [rdi]

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  client.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17336 (debuggers(dbg).150226-1500) amd64fre

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
OS Thread Id: 0x584 (51)
Current frame: 
Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00000000630c4029 to 00000000631fbceb

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`3a37f3a0 00000000`630c4029 : 00000000`0000001e 00000000`63070b8e 00000000`1005a720 00000000`0000000d : ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+0xee8a4b
00000000`3a37f820 00000000`63070b8e : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000050 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+0xdb0d89
00000000`3a37f860 00000000`63072415 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000042 00000000`63072290 00000000`63055333 : ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+0xd5d8ee
00000000`3a37f8d0 00000000`63054988 : 00000000`1005a720 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`079f2f00 : ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+0xd5f175
00000000`3a37f900 00000000`6305748c : 00000000`1005a720 00000000`1009d9d8 00000000`3a37f9e0 00000000`00000000 : ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+0xd416e8
00000000`3a37f960 00000000`63053899 : 00000000`1005a720 00000000`1009d970 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+0xd441ec
00000000`3a37fa30 00000000`6cfa1d9f : 00000000`1009d970 00000000`1005a720 00000000`1009d9d8 00000000`1009d9d8 : ImageViewerDotNet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+0xd405f9
00000000`3a37fa90 00000000`6cfa1e3b : 00000000`6d032ac0 00000000`10076d40 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : msvcr100!endthreadex+0x43
00000000`3a37fac0 00000000`77a559ed : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : msvcr100!endthreadex+0xdf
00000000`3a37faf0 00000000`77b8b831 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
00000000`3a37fb20 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d


SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  imageviewerdotnet!boost::serialization::singleton<NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer>::get_const_instance+ee8a4b

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: ImageViewerDotNet

IMAGE_NAME:  ImageViewerDotNet.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5187ed93

STACK_COMMAND:  ~51s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_c0000005_ImageViewerDotNet.dll!boost::serialization::singleton_NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer_::get_const_instance

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_imageviewerdotnet!boost::serialization::singleton_NmXerces::CmLibraryInitializer_::get_const_instance+ee8a4b

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:wrong_symbols_c0000005_imageviewerdotnet.dll!boost::serialization::singleton_nmxerces::cmlibraryinitializer_::get_const_instance

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {a7d099ff-a825-ee55-6e51-303340f35724}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: AccessViolation is like a NullReferenceException. You seem to have many threads (see `~51s`) and there seems to be a singleton. If that singleton creation method is not thread safe, this could cause such a problem

Comment: Thank you Thomas.  Appreciate you taking the time to look through that.  I just solved the issue in a different manner.  Used a newer version of the client.exe software which didn't crash and is still compatible with our server.  Didn't answer why the above version crashes on only one Windows 7 computer though.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Do I need to mark this as solved or something?  Don't want to waste anyone else's valuable time.

Comment: Mine was just a comment, not an answer. Maybe just delete the question, otherwise it will be closed by the community as "cannot be reproduced any more"

Comment: Post your own answer and then accept it. Explain what happened briefly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the issue in a different manner. Used a newer version of the client.exe software which didn't crash and is still compatible with our server. Didn't answer why the above version crashes on only one Windows 7 computer though. Thanks again!!